# Concatenating Null values in DCount query that compare to corresponding concatenated table fields

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Using Access 2007.

I have to compare several data entry fields with their corresponding tables fields. If the fields match, do not add a new record. If not, add a new record with the values.

```
AnimalInfo Table fields
WHno (Wildlife Health Number)
Species
LETClr1 (Left Ear Tag Color 1)
LETNo1 (Left Ear Tag Number 1)
LETClr2 (Left Ear Tag Color 2)
LETNo2 (Left Ear Tag Number 2)
RETClr1 (Right Ear Tag Color 1)
RETNo1 (Right Ear Tag Number 1)
RETClr2 (Right Ear Tag Color 2)
RETNo2 (Right Ear Tag Number 2)

Form F_HotelForm unbound fields
txtSpecies
txtLETClr1 
txtLETNo1 
txtLETClr2
txtLETNo2
txtRETClr1
txtRETNo1
txtRETClr2
txtRETNo2
```

I am trying to create a DCount to check and see if there are any matching records. The animal's uniqueness is determined by its species and ear tag information. It can have one ear tag number and color, or four. (Some of the older data has none but I can't do anything about that! In those cases, a new record, i.e. new Wildlife Health Number will be generated)

This is what I want to accomplish with this form:

If there are no matching fields (DCount = 0) add a new record and update fields from the form into table.

If there is 1 matching record, then the animal's wildlife health number is displayed (in a new form eventually)

If there are multiple records, then these are displayed in another form and the user needs to pick the correct animal.

LETClr1 and LETNo1 are paired.

LETClr2 and LETNo2 are paired.

RETClr1 and RETNo1 are paired.

RETClr2 and RETNo2 are paired.

Any and all of these fields could have values or not. Left ear tag numbers and colors could have been entered as either LETClr1 or LETClr2 so I have to compare both LETClr1 and LETClr2 with the txtLETClr1 data entry. (This holds true for all paired fields)

Below is a sample of the script so far. It is very rudimentary as I am very new to this and am just trying to see what works.

```
Private Sub GenerateWHno_Click()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

If IsNull(Forms!F_HotelEntry!txtSpecies) Or (Forms!F_HotelEntry!txtSpecies) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Species is a required field. Please enter a species"
    Exit Sub

End If


MsgBox txtSpecies
SpeciesCount = DCount("[Species]", "AnimalInfo", "[Species]= '" & txtSpecies & "'AND [L_ET_Color1]='" & txtL_ET_Color1 & "' AND [L_ET_No1]='" & txtL_ET_No1 & "'")
    If SpeciesCount > 1 Then
        MsgBox SpeciesCount & " Greater than 1"
    ElseIf SpeciesCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You need a new WHno"

        WHno = Nz(DMax("WHno", "AnimalInfo")) + 1
        MsgBox WHno

        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("AnimalInfo")
            rs.AddNew
            rs!WHno = WHno
            rs!Species = txtSpecies
            rs!L_ET_Color1 = txtL_ET_Color1
            rs!L_ET_No1 = txtL_ET_No1
            rs!R_ET_Color2 = txtR_ET_Color2
            rs.Update
            rs.Close
    Else

    End If
    Forms!F_HotelEntry!txtSpecies = ""
    Forms!F_HotelEntry!txtL_ET_Color1 = ""
    Forms!F_HotelEntry!txtL_ET_No1 = ""
End Sub
```

So the problem is that I cannot concatenate NULL fields. The DCount only works if there is Non Null data in the form/table.

Any ideas as to how I can work around this?

Many thanks.

My comments are getting garbled so I am putting below original posting.

I copied the suggested code into module and rewrote query a couple of different way but still got error message: Run-time error 424. Object required

SpeciesCount = DCount("[Species]", "AnimalInfo", "[Species] = txtSpecies AND (is_null([L_ET_Color1],"""") = is_null(txtL_ET_Color1,""""))")

SpeciesCount = DCount("[Species]", "AnimalInfo", "[Species] = '" & txtSpecies & "'AND is_null([L_ET_Color1],"") ='" & is_null(txtL_ET_Color1, "") & "' AND [L_ET_No1]='" & txtL_ET_No1 & "'")

I have been tinkering with this for 3 hours and am no closer to a solution. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In a module create the following function:

```
public function is_null(ctl as variant, nullreplace as string) as variant
    if ctl is null then
        is_null = nullreplace
    else
        is_null = ctl
    end if
end function
```

In your query change your reference to a given field, yourField to is_null(yourField, "").

In a string enclosed in double quotes, this will need to be is_null(yourField, """") (it needs a double-quote to escape a double-quote, so 4 is 2 internally)

Comment: SpeciesCount = DCount("[Species]", "AnimalInfo", "[Species] = txtSpecies AND (is_null([L_ET_Color1],"""") = is_null(txtL_ET_Color1,""""))")
    'SpeciesCount = DCount("[Species]", "AnimalInfo", "[Species] = '" & txtSpecies & "'AND is_null([L_ET_Color1],"") ='" & is_null(txtL_ET_Color1, "") & "' AND [L_ET_No1]='" & txtL_ET_No1 & "'") 
    'Run-time error 424. Object required

Comment: My comment/question above is garbled so I put it at the end of my original post.